# I am trying to parse an HTML Table into a database for a website

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am taking a report that I am getting and trying to parse it into a database. here is the code I'm using in python 3:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from models import *

import os # File I/O
import time
import datetime
import shutil
import glob
import configparser
config_parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
config_parser.read("config.ini")

pdownload_dir = os.path.abspath('./prism_downloads/')
dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())
filelist = glob.glob(pdownload_dir + '/*.html')
dbpath = ('./db')
def db_Prism():

    database.connect()
    database.create_tables([Prism])
    database.close()

    for root, dir, files in os.walk(pdownload_dir):
        for file in files:
            print(file)
            file_markup = ''
            with open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(pdownload_dir, file)), 'r') as html:
                file_markup = html.read()
            if file_markup == '':
                print('ERROR: File was not read')
            print('Reading {0} into BS4'.format(file))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(file_markup, 'html.parser')
            print('File parsed')
            data = []
            table = soup.find('table')
            rows = table.find_all('tr') # 18th row is header row 
            cols = rows[0].find_all('td')
            cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols] 
            database.connect()
            for row in rows[0:]:
                d = row.find_all('td')
                d = [ele.text.strip() for ele in d]
                data.append([ele for ele in d if ele]) # Get rid of empty values 
                Prism.create(pmt_id=(d[0]),
                    old_status=(d[2]),
                    new_status=(d[3]),
                    last_updated=float(d[4]))
            database.close()
```

Here is the code from the report:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" align="Left">
                                <strong>
                                    <div style="font:verdana; font-size:20px;">Report Generated for 02/26/2018</div>
                                </strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    <tr bgcolor="#C0C0C0">

                                <th width="112">
                                    <b>
                                        <div style="font:verdana">PRISMID</div>
                                    </b>
                                </th>

                                <th width="192">
                                    <b>
                                        <div style="font:verdana">Project_Name</div>
                                    </b>
                                </th>

                                <th width="160">
                                    <b>
                                        <div style="font:verdana">Old_Status</div>
                                    </b>
                                </th>

                                <th width="160">
                                    <b>
                                        <div style="font:verdana">New_Status</div>
                                    </b>
                                </th>

                                <th width="192">
                                    <b>
                                        <div style="font:verdana">Last_Updated</div>
                                    </b>
                                </th>

                    </tr>

                            <tr bgcolor="#999999">

                                <td width="112" align="Left">
                                    <div align="Left" style="font-face:verdana;">
                                        262712f 
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td width="288" align="Left">
                                    <div align="Left" style="font-face:verdana;">
                                        eCDW U2L 1705-1707 
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td width="144" align="Left">
                                    <div align="Left" style="font-face:verdana;">
                                        Cancelled 
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td width="176" align="Left">
                                    <div align="Left" style="font-face:verdana;">
                                        In Progress 
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td width="336" align="Left">
                                    <div align="Left" style="font-face:verdana;">
                                        02/26/2018 9:15:28 AM 
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                        </tr>
```

Now the code for the report is freaking crazy long so I only posted part of it. all I need is listed in the Prism.create and all I want it to do is replace the data in the existing table.

Oh and here is the error I am getting in my console when I try to run it:

```
C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BudgetHome>python prism.py
1802261815.html
Reading 1802261815.html into BS4
File parsed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prism.py", line 107, in <module>
    db_Prism()
  File "prism.py", line 101, in db_Prism
    old_status=(d[2]),
IndexError: list index out of range

C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BudgetHome>
```

Any advice? Thanks again yall!

Comment: the error here is pretty clear. in your code you're referencing some array or list that you've named `d` and it either doesn't exist or is not the size you're assuming it is when you call `old_status=(d[2])`.

That loop is iterating over each element in the `td` but then referencing the `td` itself. I'd start by reconsidering that logic.

Comment: Still not making heads or tails of it. This code was written by one of my coworker and he is not available to ask about it. Can someone give me an example of what is needed or missing. He did tell me that d[0] is the first column of data (PrisimID)